# C# create instance of loaded type derivied from generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dll, casting

I have few classes and interfaces in my SDK:

```
    public interface IUser
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class SettingsBase<TUser> where TUser : IUser
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TUser> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Page<TUser> where TUser : IUser
    {
        public SettingsBase<TUser> Settings { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a .dll library with public classes:

```
public class ConfigPage : Page<User> 
{

}

public class User : IUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Settings : SettingsBase<User>
{
    private int _additionalSetting;
}
```

I want to check if .dll has ConfigPage class, derivied from Page :

```
var dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"libraryName.dll");
var type = dll.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "ConfigPage"); // the type is Page<User>
var isIUser = type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IUser));
```

Ok, everything is good, but finally my question is:

How to get access to SettingsBase Settings property?

Why this returning null? :

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Page<IUser>    // type is Page<User>, User implement IUser
```

Comment: you can not cast type to page<IUser> try to cast it to Page<User>

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I think the point is the OP does not know the specific type of `User` - they just know its an `IUser`

Comment: @up Exactly, SDK don't know User class.

Comment: @Jamiec your right, but it's wrong casting. Also if i were Pawel I use Dependency Inject instead reflector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of `null` cast-result is a fact, that generic classes are **invariant** - you cannot assign an instance of `MyClass<Base>` to a variable of type `MyClass<Derived>` or vice versa.

I suggest you to update your interfaces with the [interfaces-covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public interface IUser {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public interface ISettings<out TUser>
    where TUser : IUser {
    IEnumerable<TUser> Users { get; }
}
public interface IPage<out TUser>
    where TUser : IUser {
    ISettings<TUser> Settings { get; }
}

// Abstract implementation
public abstract class SettingsBase<TUser> : ISettings<TUser
    where TUser : IUser {
    public SettingsBase() {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<TUser>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<TUser> Users { get; private set; }
}
public abstract class Page<TUser> : IPage<TUser>
    where TUser : IUser {
    public Page() {
        Settings = CreateSettings();
    }
    public ISettings<TUser> Settings { get; private set; }
    //
    protected abstract ISettings<TUser> CreateSettings();
}
// Real implementation
public class ConfigPage : Page<User> {
    protected override ISettings<User> CreateSettings() {
        return new Settings();
    }
}
public class User : IUser {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Settings : SettingsBase<User> {
    // ...
}
```

Usage:

```
IPage<IUser> page = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConfigPage)) as IPage<IUser>;
```

Comment: This was my first thought too - I was struggling to get an example working to demonstrate in an answer: http://rextester.com/MNPMF82191 I think it takes more than what you've shown in this answer.

Comment: as Jamiec said...
I get 
(26:32) Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TUser' must be invariantly valid on 'Rextester.IPage<TUser>.Settings'. 'TUser' is covariant.
(31:40) Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TUser' must be invariantly valid on 'Rextester.ISettingsBase<TUser>.Users'. 'TUser' is covariant.

Comment: Please check the code-snippet in my updated answer - it demonstrates working code (you should omit "mutators" in interfaces chain).